# How to set mendaroty Field * color for inputtextlayout hint?

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

This is my xml file.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email*" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

i need "*" in RED color. How to do that??

Answer (score 0):

Try this attribute inside EditText in xml:

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/your_star_icon"
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this my friend it will work 100%**

```
  SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    SpannableString str1= new SpannableString("Email");
    str1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTemp)), 0, str1.length(), 0);
    builder.append(str1);

    SpannableString str2= new SpannableString("*");
    str2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, str2.length(), 0);
    builder.append(str2);

    tvtv.setHint(builder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding HTML to the string. Something like:

```
<string name="mailHint">Email <span style="color: red">*</span></string>
```

Then link it to your hint:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/mailHint" />
```

Comment: it will work if it is just Edit text but here `EditText` within `TextInputLayout`. so here it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Material Components Library.
Starting from the [**`1.2.0`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/7822b6d05e7fe890a45fe688e3dbbaf2c76d618a) you can format the hint text.

For example you can just use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:hint="@string/hint_test"
    ...>
```

with:

```
<string name="hint_test">Email <font fgcolor='#FF0000'>*</font></string>
```

[image]
[image]